# How to iterate through the infinite Cartesian product of infinite generator functions in python?

Tags: python, generator, infinite, cartesian-product

I want a generator function `product` that generates the Cartesian product of any two given generator functions `f` and `g` (i.e. if `x` can found in `f()` in finite time and `y` can be found in `g()` in finite time, then `(x,y)` should be produced from `product(f, g)` in finite time).

For example, I might want a generator function to iterate through `(x,y)` satisfying `x in itertools.count() and y in itertools.count(-1, -1)`.

What is a good way to do this? Any order is fine.

Comment: what order would that be in?  For your example, would it mean `(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), ..., (0, n), (0, n+1), ...` (ie the first iterator never goes to 1?

Comment: Rational numbers (and therefor pairs of numbers) [are enumerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function). The classic way to do this is like: `(0, 0),
 (1, 0),
 (1, 1),
 (2, 0),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 2),
 (3, 0),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 2)...` is this what you are after?

Comment: You don't have to read any further than the subject of this question to know that it has no answer.  "all permutations" and "infinite generators" are two mutually exclusive ideas.  There can be no right answer to this question.

Comment: @JonSG the pairs are countable, which means you can do this in a away that you can give me any pair and I can tell you which element in the enumeration it will be and all pairs will eventually show up. But you have to enumerate them as I describe above. You can't just go `(0, 0,), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, inf)`

Comment: Also Gavin, you can't do this with just two simple generators because they can't go backward. As you can see from the list, the same number appears more than once. An iterator only has a `next()` function.

Comment: @Mark Looks like you forgot for example `(0, 1)`, but yes, something like that is what I suspect they want (and what I implemented already...).

Comment: @Mark - For two arbitrary generators, the pairs are NOT countable no matter the order you choose in terms of sampling those generators.  The simple case is only countable because you know what it is in advance.  For that, you don't need two generators...you just need one.  In fact, the logic to produce that product would be easier with a single generator.  The whole point of a general solution is that you don't know anything about the two generators.

Comment: You can @CryptoFool. You just need to be willing to use `tee`, `enumerate` and `islice`. This will let you replay the inner generator.

Comment: @Mark - so then define the logic for when you'd stop accepting new items from a generator and "rewind" to reuse ones you've used before.  In the general case, what would lead you to know that you can or should do that?  I think I see what you're getting at, but it doesn't work.  What you're doing is choosing a way to implement a solution where the order of access of the two generators is countable.  That's a totally different thing than producing a series of terms that is countable.

Comment: Sorry I meant generator functions, not arbitrary generators. This is not that hard to do when you have the function for the generator. And a product, not permutations

Comment: @CryptoFool I'm not sure what you think "countable" means but if you think the Cartesian product of two countable sets is not necessarily countable, then you are mistaken about some basic definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Gavin's earlier self-product solution, this progresses by expanding the "square" of visited pairs (if you imagine them laid out in 2D, one axis for the first generator and the other for the other).

```
from itertools import count, repeat

def product(f, g):
    for i, x, y in zip(count(), f(), g()):
        yield from zip(repeat(x, i), g())
        yield from zip(f(), repeat(y, i+1))
```

Demo, the product of the positive ints and the negative ints:

```
for p in product(lambda: count(1), lambda: count(-1, -1)):
    print(p)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY67DsMgDEV3vsIjqHRAXar8TRogtZTElkuk0p@nkMfQoXfwYJ374JyetNzuLKVEoRkwBUlE0wtwZpIEA61LsiCBQ5@U8iECC/l1SDpaGE2noCqSAFp4W8iAC3yQ9WbUxkJsZ9TmQJsyhsnDVtjQPVxXNx7oP3LLOvBc8YurrGrt3HrPZVM/P3zf7eO1q57fz9VZuLpzEQvWH5tSvg)):

```
(1, -1)
(2, -1)
(1, -2)
(2, -2)
(3, -1)
(3, -2)
(1, -3)
(2, -3)
(3, -3)
(4, -1)
(4, -2)
(4, -3)
(1, -4)
(2, -4)
(3, -4)
(4, -4)
(5, -1)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

```
import itertools

def product(fn1, fn2):
    def product_part(fnx, fny):
      for i, x in enumerate(fnx()):
          for y in itertools.islice(fny(), i):
              yield x, y
    prod_a = zip(fn1(), fn2())
    prod_b = product_part(fn1, fn2)
    prod_c = ((x, y) for y, x in product_part(fn2, fn1))
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(prod_a, prod_b, prod_c))
```

Comment: This doesn't get you there for even a single arbitrary generator.  How about a generator that returns all of the even integers followed by all the odd integers?  That generator returns an infinite non-repeating sequence of integers, and yet there's no way to sample it to get a set that will eventually return every potential value.

Comment: @CryptoFool *"How about a generator that returns all of the even integers followed by all the odd integers?"* - That's impossible and thus irrelevant.

Comment: @KellyBundy - what do you mean "impossible"?  It's a generator that I can implement in a few lines of code.  The question does not put any restraints on the characteristics of the generators involved.  It says "any other generator".  Even if you read between the lines and infer that it means a generator that produces a non-repeating set of integers, which is by all means an infinitely small set compared to "all generators", such a generator can lead to the question being unanswerable.  So again, for "any other generator", which is in the statement of the problem, the problem has no answer.

Comment: @CryptoFool *"It's a generator that I can implement"* - No you can't.

Comment: What do you mean?  I certainly can.  In fact, I just did.  I just implement a generator that returns 0, 2, 4, 6...  That's a generator that first produces all of the even integers and then produces all of the odd integers. - that it won't ever return an odd integer isn't a problem.  Rather, it's the whole point of why this question is ill defined.

Comment: @CryptoFool *"I just did"* - Show it then.

Comment: @CryptoFool *"it won't ever return an odd integer"* - Oh good, you agree that it doesn't do what you claimed it does, and hence that you hadn't done what you claimed you had done. That was quick :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy - but it's a valid generator.  It's even a generator that satisfies every simple constraint that you could possibly put on a generator.  But no constraints were put on how a generator has to act.  The point of this simple example though is that this is a generator that satisfies any constraint of both "orderliness" and "exhaustiveness" that you could define, and yet STILL leads to the question being unanswerable.

Comment: @KellyBundy - here's the simplest way I can put this.  If you change the question to constrain the two generators to both producing countable sequences of non-repeating integers, THEN you can write a piece of code that can produce a countable sequence of all pairs of values returned by the two generators.  But if either generator produces a non-countable sequence, nothing you can do can produce all combinations of values involving that generator that will be countable.  Since the question doesn't place this constraint on the two generators, it has no answer.

Comment: @CryptoFool You're not making any sense.

Comment: @KellyBundy - Ah ha!  You've degenerated our argument to an Ad Hominem attack!  I win!!!

Comment: @CryptoFool Lol. You wish.

Comment: Maybe helpful to decide what you mean by countable. In this context I would define countable to mean there is a one-to-one correspondence between elements of the sequence and the natural numbers. In other words, given any non-negative integer `i` and can ask for and get the `i`th element from the sequence. This will be true for all infinite generators. Given any two such sequences, it is possible to create a new countable sequence of pairs — this was proven a long time ago. Whether you can do that *efficiently* starting with python iterators is a different question.

Comment: A consequence of this is that given *any* two infinite generators it *is* possible to make a new sequence that if left to run long enough will generate an arbitrary pair from the two original sequences.

Comment: @Mark - what you are saying is only true if you include the generator itself in the truth set.  If you can't refer to how the generators compute each value, then in general, it's trivial to produce a sequence for which there is no "algorithm" for determining the index value of a sequence element.  If the algorithm for what the index is for any particular value in a sequence is "where the element falls in the sequence produced by generator X", then fine, it's countable.  But then my simple example by definition returns a countable sequence.  A statement to the contrary is what started all this.

Comment: `my simple example` .. @CryptoFool sorry, I'm a little lost in the comments. Which example are you talking about?

Comment: oops..not what I posted there for a second...rather, my answer to this question.

Comment: @Mark - don't worry about this.  It's all academic and silly.  What we really needed was to understand what the OP was actually trying to accomplish.  In the absence of that information, all of this is just wasting time on a Sunday afternoon. - all I was really trying to argue is that the question is ill defined.  I stand by that statement.